# How do I ensure that I run the code I've just installed?

Tags: android

Developing on Android, very often the following happens:

- I export a release build of my application, I install it on the device and I run it.
- I do some changes. I export it again
- I reinstall it on the device
- I kill EVERYTHING from the Task Manager
- I run the installation again

So I would expect the newly installed version of the application to be run. But instead, I'm still running the old code. I can tell it for sure because I've added some Log.d() traces and they don't show up in the logs.

So, I guess the old version of the classes are still somewhere in memory and the new ones are not loaded until.......... until something.

So what do I have to do (except reboot, please) in order to make sure that when I run the application, I run the newly installed one?

Isn't killing the application enough?

I'd hate to have to uninstall it before reinstall, for several reasons. Or is that the only way?

Comment: ? Why dont you just click run. It updates the new one and runs it for you. as long as your android is plugged in.

Comment: You can rename the new built and then try to install so that it may not override the old one.But Atlast you have to Uninstall every Release.

Comment: Buy a USB cable, plug your phone, enable USB debugging. Then just Run As ->　android application in eclipse.

Comment: @Calvin, I know how to debug via USB, but I asked how to _install_ a _release build_ and make sure it runs instead of running a version that has already been overwritten. Sometimes one needs to test "the real thing". Also, debugging via USB still obliges me to uninstall the release build, otherwise the debug build refuses to install and run

Comment: My question also applies to no developing at all. You download and install a new version of an application you already had, you run it, and it may happen to be running the old version just because you had run it minutes before. So I guess the answer is you just _cannot_ force the old version to be unloaded from memory without uninstalling first or rebooting. I don't see why the question is so stupid, though.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to keep it in debug mode.

If you are swapping, then yes you need to keep uninstalling.

From what Ive seen, Debug version is exactly the same as the release version, and I only put the release version on at the very end to ensure its all ok, and then to actually release it.

Uninstalling the app, then reinstalling should 100% run the new code. Even things like stored app data would be lost, due to unassociation - different signature (For the exact reason you need to uninstall first).

You can always try increasing the version number, and see if that installs over the top, without the need to uninstall. Something I've not tested, but something that would be quite useful.

Make sure you are building it successfully. And ensure you are taking the correct APK, aka not an old one. (I overwrite my old APK when I build). As long as it was successful, you will have the new code. Maybe your build fails, and so you are mistakingly taking a non-updated APK.

I still recommend Debug mode however. It makes deployment for testing more efficient, and I have not noticed any difference.

Hope some of this helps.